# Trying to improve performance on a badly designed table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table, which unfortunately, got designed in an interesting way. It has 30 columns which are all `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. It was designed to be a quick 'data warehouse style' table, but it's transactional.

One column is a `bit`, called `IsPhysical`. The table has a PK, and that's all as far as indexing. All those `NVARCHAR` columns are used within `WHERE` clauses. The table isn't massive. Between 100K rows and 500k.

But because of the type of queries we do, which are often,

```
WHERE 
    ISNULL(a.ColumnA, '') = ISNULL(b.ColumnA, '') 
    AND ISNULL(a.ColumnB, '') = ISNULL(b.ColumnB, '')`
```

where `ColumnA`, `ColumnB` etc are of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

We're suffering from some performance issues.

Two columns we often have in our `WHERE` clause are `IsActive` and `IsPhysical`. So, I was going to apply an index on those, to see if we can get any benefit.

So prior to that, I did a query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE IsActive = 1
```

What I found strange was: why does the execution plan report a 'Clustered index scan' on that query? The table has a clustered index on the Id column - which is a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`. I'm not sure what the benefit of a clustered index on a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` is, but that's something else to investigate.

99% of activity on the table are reads. So, I was hoping to apply indexes to some of those columns, but because they're `NVARCHAR(MAX)` - that option is not available. And changing them to `VARCHAR(800)` would break the 8000 byte row limitation.

So my only option to TRY help things, is to index those `IsPhysical` and `IsActive` columns, and maybe change the index type on the PK? But not sure why, before adding indexes to those columns, I'm getting a 'Clustered index scan'.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM MyTable where IsActive = 1` would only use an index if one is available. Has it been created yet? If so, what is the ratio of IsActive 'true'? Remember that if an index doesn't have good utilization SQL Server may not select it because using it and then 'seeking back' into the Clustered Index (ie. physical table data) *may* be 'much more expensive'. Also, make sure to update stats so that query planner has good confidence that 'only a relatively small subset' of rows are IsActive 'true':} I would definitely try to index IsActive/IsPhysical (perhaps in the same index) first..

Comment: I mean you could have a computed column `ISNULL(LEFT(ColumnName, 20), '')` that indexes the first 20 characters of each column and adjust your SQL appropriately. `WHERE IndexedComputedColumn = LEFT(@String, 20) AND NonIndexedColumn = @String` i.e. give SQL Server some hints but it sounds like the table structure is fundamentally bad. (And you say as much.)

Comment: @user2864740 - I have 120K rows with IsActive = 1 and 46K where IsPhysical = 0. I have not applied any indexes yet. All the table has is the clustered index on the Id column. I'll look into updating the stats.

Comment: @ta.speot.is - So, is my understanding right - created a computed column for all the NVARCHAR columns, using only the first X chars (For example, the first 120), and put an index on that computed column? I've never thought of this or thought it to be possible.

Comment: @Craig Double-remember: In that case, one needs to use the short **and** long columns/data in each query. Using the short columns are to 'help the query planner choose indices' and the long columns are to compare actual data.. try some indexes, flush caches / update stats, run queries and compare the plan selection. Hopefully on a non-prod DB..

Comment: Bit columns are not selective enough to be useful in an index (so they won't be used). Indexes that _contain_ bit columns along with other columns, or indexes that are _filtered_ on bit columns are useful indexes.

Comment: In a typical decision support database, a table like this is a staging table. It's purpose is to get external data into a database table. Data in a staging table is processed into an actual reporting table. So it would make sense to preserve this table but create a reporting table which is optimised for reporting, and point your reports at the reporting table (for example fact and dimension tables)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should decide what you want to do about `NULL` values, or indexes are not going to be very useful.

If your queries are really of this form:

```
WHERE ISNULL(a.ColumnA, '') = ISNULL(b.ColumnA, '') AND
      ISNULL(a.ColumnB, '') = ISNULL(b.ColumnB, '')
```

Note:  Putting `JOIN` conditions in a `WHERE` clause doesn't make sense.  These conditions should probably be in an `ON` clause.

You may just want to replace `NULL` values with empty strings:

```
update t
    set columnA = coalesce(columnA, ''),
        columnB = coalesce(columnB, '')
    where columnA is null or columnB is null;
```

This will make it easier to use indexes.

Then you mention a limitation on `varchar(800)`.  No such limitation exists.  Larger string values are stored on auxiliary pages.  This is actually explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/pages-and-extents-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-2017):

> Rows cannot span pages, however portions of the row may be moved off
>   the row's page so that the row can actually be very large. The maximum
>   amount of data and overhead that is contained in a single row on a
>   page is 8,060 bytes (8 KB). However, this does not include the data
>   stored in the Text/Image page type.
>
> This restriction is relaxed for tables that contain varchar, nvarchar,
>   varbinary, or sql_variant columns. When the total row size of all
>   fixed and variable columns in a table exceeds the 8,060 byte
>   limitation, SQL Server dynamically moves one or more variable length
>   columns to pages in the ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA allocation unit, starting
>   with the column with the largest width.

So, you can reduce the column sizes, making indexes more practicable.

Comment: 1) There *is* a restriction is on the size of the index, not the (already stored) data. [Index sizes limited to 900/1700 bytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017): "..the combined sizes of the data in those columns can never exceed the limit [of the index]". 2) `varchar(max)` columns *can't* be part of the primary index key (although I believe can be in the include columns); so this would require a column type change.

Comment: The OP already has `varchar(max)` columns, so the proposed change is to make them usable for an index usage, the assertion about the '8000 row size' limit aside.

Comment: @user2864740 . . . There is no issue with reducing the size of the columns to a length of 800 and building a separate index on each column.  That is how I interpreted what the OP wants to do.  Of course, a composite index on all the columns might still exceed the maximum index size.  But a single column can't pose a danger if declared as `varchar(800)`.